# Getting slow response while hitting https url and fetching the data in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

In ViewDidLoad method I have added the below code

```
      self.responseData = [NSMutableData data];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:
                                        [NSURL URLWithString:@"my url"]];
        [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:YES];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
        NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        [connection start];

And When connection start delegate methods are calling

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

        NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
        NSUInteger responseStatusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];
        _responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

        NSLog(@"connection");
    }

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
        // Append the new data to the instance variable you declared
        [_responseData appendData:data];
        NSLog(@"_responseData%@",_responseData);

    }

    - (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
                      willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse*)cachedResponse {

        // Return nil to indicate not necessary to store a cached response for this connection
        return nil;
    }

    - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
        NSError *jError;
        jArray= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jError];    
        [_tableView reloadData];    
    }

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
        NSLog(@"didFailWithError");
    }
```

This is the way am hitting HTTPS URL but it was taking more time to display the data.Am not getting what is the issue.Can anyone please help me on this issue.

Comment: What do you mean by 'taking more time'?   How long is it taking to make the request and return the data?  How much data is returned?  What type of connection are you using (WiFi, 3G, GPRS)?

Comment: @ananthi Try testing the API on plugins like postman to check if the API is responding fast on other platform or not. How can you be sure that API itself is not taking time to respond ???

Comment: @ananthi One more suggestion that NSURLConnection class is deprecated from iOS 9. This class may remove in future. Start using NSURLSession Class.

Comment: Thanks everyone issue got.Problem is my userId authentication it tooks more time.So am using NSUserDefaults to fix this issue.